# monk find returning bizarre json

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So in node I have this code, which is totally trivial...but it isn't working.

```
var collection = db.get('fisforfriends');
var db = monk('localholst:27017/fisforfriends');
...
var userName = req.body.username;
```

The above works for insertion. Just showing to you guys = ) !

```
console.log(collection.find({}, {username: userName}));
```

Prints a ton of text that I have at the bottom.

*That element doesn't exist in the database, but my function for adding an element worked the other day so I am not worried about that. The function adds it if it doesn't exist*.

All I have is the console.log call that is printing all of that. I was hoping to have it just print 'false' or something.

```
9 Dec 22:54:27 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Express server listening on port 3000
GET / 200 319ms - 427b
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 4ms
{ col:
   { manager:
      { driver: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _events: {} },
     driver:
      { emitter: [Object],
        state: 0,
        _dbconn: [Object],
        db: null,
        username: '',
        password: undefined,
        admin: [Object],
        _collections: [Object],
        bson_serializer: [Object],
        ObjectID: [Object] },
     name: 'fisforfriends',
     col:
      { emitter: [Object],
        state: 0,
        options: undefined,
        skinDb: [Object],
        ObjectID: [Object],
        collectionName: 'fisforfriends',
        collection: null,
        internalHint: null,
        hint: [Getter/Setter] },
     options: {} },
  type: 'find',
  completed: false,
  opts: { username: 'fa', fields: {}, safe: true },
  _events:
   { error: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] },
     success: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] } },
  fulfill: [Function],
  query: {} }
9 Dec 22:54:45 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
9 Dec 22:54:45 - [nodemon] C:\Users\hassan\Documents\Hassans_Bravery\fisforfrien
ds\routes\index.js
```

Comment: well looks like a promise to me

Comment: Look in the [documentation](https://npmjs.org/package/monk), its given `All methods that perform an async action return a promise.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i suggested above this is not the object from the database this is the promise that will return the object when it has finished executing

Database calls are almost allways asynchronous and especially in the case of node.js which is event driven. This means it takes time, but your `console.log`executes immediatly. The result wont be there.

If i take a look at the docs, the second param is the callback function you pass in which will retrieve the object from the query

So you can either do

```
users.find({}).on('success', function (doc) { /* doc is the result available here */ });
```

or

```
users.find({}, function (err, docs){ /* doc is the result available here */ });
```